# Django Linking an account details with checkout in ecommerce apllication

Tags: django

I have a django ecommerce application which customers are enabled to create account and setting up their shipping and billing address. In the application there is ability to checkout carts which I have designed the code and now what I want to do which I am confused about is how to create shipping app which contains the shipping and billing address of the customer and he/she would be able to select it anytime he/ she wants to checkout or add another address to the already stored address to reflect in the product order checkout. below is my code for the user registration and my checkout.

**Accounts models**

```
class BaseOrderInfo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    # shipping information
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

# Create your models here.
class Account(BaseOrderInfo):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='account')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Account for {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

**Order models**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    # each individual status
    SUBMITTED = 1
    PROCESSED = 2
    SHIPPED = 3
    CANCELLED = 4

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='user_account')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon, related_name='orders', null=True, blank=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    # set of possible order statuses
    ORDER_STATUSES = (
        (SUBMITTED, 'Submitted'), (PROCESSED, 'Processed'), (SHIPPED, 'Shipped'), (CANCELLED, 'Cancelled'),)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUSES, default=SUBMITTED)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        total_cost = sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())
        return total_cost - total_cost * (self.discount / Decimal('100'))


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

**Order views**

```
@login_required
def account(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {
        'user': user
    }
    template = 'account.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def load_account(user):
    try:
        return user.account
    except:  # this is not great, but trying to keep it simple
        account = Account.objects.create(user=user)
        return account


def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if account.is_authenticated:
        for item in cart:
            OrderItem.objects.create(
                order=order,
                product=item['product'],
                price=item['price'],
                quantity=item['quantity']
            )
        cart.clear()
        order_created.delay(order.id)  # set the order in the session
        request.session['order_id'] = order.id
        return redirect(reverse('payment:process'))
        context = {
            'order': order,
        }
        template = 'order/created.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        return redirect('account:update_account')
    context = {
        'cart': cart,
        'form': form,
    }
    template = 'order/create.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

further codes would be supplied on request

Comment: What do you mean by "link the created profile which contains the shipping and billing address to the product order checkout"? Try writing in more technical terms.

Comment: done. modified the question. Thanks in advance